# Use Dropbox/Google Drive or any alternative as a ftp server to store app data

Tags: android, file-upload, dropbox, google-drive-api

My app generates a xml file on the users phone from a sqlite-db. 
Is there a possibility to send this file to a remote server so I can work with it? What is the best practice? Is there a possibility to use Dropbox or Google Drive for my purposes (use a public link from my account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern that I use to send remotely a file is the following:

- I send the file as a mail attachment to a "service" gmail account
- a script process the inbox, and store the file in gdrive

In this way, I don't have to set up a public ftp server.

The same thing can be done using Evernote: you can send the attachment to an evernote mail address, linked to your account, and have it styled in a notebook. There isa public sdk, that allow you to process the notebook, and reverie the attachment.

Ciao

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use dropbox. Dropbox has an api that you can use. If you can have your own ftp server, it's the best option. you can create a simple FTP client with in your app.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any tutorial how to setup a Dropbox folder to upload the files from the app?

Comment: Here is the documentation https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/android

Comment: If I am right, the user has to login with theri account?! Thats not what I want. I do not want the user to login but upload the files to MY folder.

Comment: then you can use a dummy account and use it for all the users. But its not correct way to do. You can have your own ftp server.